# Ansible : Split a string with multiple spaces as delimiter

Tags: ansible

I am trying to split a string multiple spaces as delimiter in Ansible.

```
 - name: Build Archive files 123.
    set_fact:
      archfilesloc: "{{ archfiles.split(\" +\")[1] }}" doesnt work
 - name: Build Archive files 123.
    set_fact:
      archfilesloc: "{{ archfiles.split(\"\\s+\")[1] }}"doesnt work
 - name: Build Archive files 123.
    set_fact:
      archfilesloc: "{{ archfiles.split(\"[\\s+]\")[1] }}" doesnt work
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. For your potential next questions, I suggest you: 1) give an exact example of your input 2) give an exact example of the expected result 3) define as precisely as possible "doesn't work". Those elements were quite easy too guess here but you should not rely on reader's interpretation to get an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

```
archfiles.split()[1]
```

Here, `split()` is a Python function and behaves exactly like it does in python.

See: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-string-split/